# Pandas: Aggregating List Values in Columns

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'VehID' : pd.Series([10000,10000,10000,10001,10001,10001,10001]),
        'JobNo' : pd.Series([1,2,2,1,2,3,3]),
        'Material' : pd.Series([5005,5100,5005,5888,5222,5888,5222])}
df   = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['VehID','JobNo','Material'])
```

It looks like this:

```
   VehID    JobNo  Material
0  10000      1      5005
1  10000      2      5100
2  10000      2      5005
3  10001      1      5888
4  10001      2      5222
5  10001      3      5888
6  10001      3      5222
```

I would like to identify the materials that occur in consecutive jobs for every vehicle. For example,

```
VehID  Material  Jobs
10000    5005    [1,2]
10001    5222    [2,3]
```

I would like to avoid working with for loops. Does anyone have any suggestions on a neat solution to this? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

You can first gather data to lists with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) constructor as a function:

```
>>> res = df.groupby(['VehID', 'Material'])['JobNo'].apply(list).reset_index()
>>> res
   VehID  Material   JobNo
0  10000      5005  [1, 2]
1  10000      5100     [2]
2  10001      5222  [2, 3]
3  10001      5888  [1, 3]
```

And now you can filter out all non-consecutive lists:

```
>>> f = res.JobNo.apply(lambda x: len(x) > 1 and sorted(x) == range(min(x), max(x)+1))
>>> res[f]
   VehID  Material   JobNo
0  10000      5005  [1, 2]
2  10001      5222  [2, 3]
```

You can probably speed it with smarter functions - first store alreadt sorted list in `res` and then check min, max and len with range of same length

Comment: cool. I am also learning Pandas, I am working on Dataframe which have around 50K to 80K entries. Above is helpful to me. Appreciate `sorted(x) == range(min(x), max(x)+1)` logic to check consecutive jobs